# Using loop to put string stored in arrays in specific line of specific file

Tags: bash, shell, loops, text, sed

I have a code that cuts-delim the content of a txt file in different arrays. First field contains filename, second line number, third string to add.

Sample text:

```
create_tetro.c:132://   printf("\t\t\tSol %d found !\n", sol);
float_to_int.c:23://    printf("%f -> %d\n", i, ((int)i / 1) + 0.9999);
free_all.c:19:  printf("update_pieces\n");
```

Code for assigning content to the arrays:

```
i=0

while read line; do
{
file[$i]="$(cut -d ':' -f1 <<< $line)"
line_nb[$i]="$(cut -d ':' -f2 <<< $line)"
string[$i]="$(cut -d ':' -f3 <<< $line)"
((i++))
}
done < .gres.txt
```

The above part is correct and functional. I would like now to use the arrays in a loop to add `$string[i]` at `$line_nb[i]` in `$file[i]` using `sed -i` or something else. To put it in other terms, I want to add the lines contained in the array inside some .c files at some specific lines. This will be called by a Makefile rule named "print debug" and will automatically replace all of the debugging printfs in the corresponding files at the right line. This doesn't work but is close:

```
for i in {1..150}; do sed -i '' "${line_nb[$i]}i${string[$i]}" ${file[i]};done
```

I've checked many resources, documentations, videos, questions but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: what happens next will probably dictate the best approach.

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: I have edited and added more information to make my problem clearer.

Comment: No, what's not clear is what your attempt *does* do, and how that differs from what you *want* it to do.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) points to `$(string[$i])` and says "This is a glob used as a command name. Was it supposed to be in ${..}"

Comment: @thatotherguy yes sorry it was a syntax mistake on my end when I pasted the code in SO. It didn't fix the problem though but will help for reading's clarity.

Comment: @Aboitier Please make sure to paste the actual code you run. Please do not write it by hand or post code that's "basically the same thing" as what you actually run. If you don't want to post your actual code, please write a second example that you're comfortable posting, *run that first*, and then post that code and its result

Comment: @thatotherguy yes of course. Will definitely do. Thanks for telling me about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you need the arrays at this point, but I'll assume you do.

> Update

You are inserting program code, so your "str" is getting metacharacters such as backslashes. I added a line to escape the escape sequences, but parsing things that might be commands for the parser is at best something to be very careful about.

Try this.

```
declare -i i=0
while IFS=: read -r target lno str
do file[i]="$target"
   line_nb[i]="$lno"
   str="${str//\\/\\\\}"
   string[i++]="$str"
   sed -i "$lno i\\$str" $target
done < "$1"
```

You might want to back up all your target files before you try this, though. ;)

Comment: You'll need to fix the `i` command, which is what the OP is probably having trouble with.

Comment: Mine worked, but it's [GNU](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands). I don't know if non-GNU works without the backslash. Will test and add either way, since it's more portable.

Comment: Thanks Paul! It helped me a lot. As @chepner said, I still have a problem with the i command. sed: 1: "create_tetro.c": command c expects \ followed by text

Comment: If using variables, you will need double-quotes. That means you will need TWO backslashes (like behind the `i` command above.)

Comment: Indeed Paul, that's what I did. But I got this error even with double quotes around the last "$target" variable. It seems that instead of reading the whole $target variable, sed only reads the first letter of it and takes it as an argument. For example when $target = float.c, I receive: "sed: 1: "float.c": invalid command code f"

Comment: Thanks @PaulHodges for the edit of your answer. The  `done < "$1"` is giving me the `"No such file or directory"` error. Any idea why this does not work ?

Comment: I made it work. I just replaced the "$1" by my original .gres.txt file and I changed 'sed -i "$lno i\\$str" $target' by 'sed -i "$lno i\\$str" >> $target'. My files are modified perfectly! Thanks again for the great help

Comment: Glad you got it. The `$1` was assuming the filename would be passed into the script of maybe function.